# Hide file access implementation details while using TDD

Tags: c++, interface, tdd

I'm trying to create a CsvTableFile class which inherits from a TableFileInterface. In order to unit test the class I want to mock out all file accesses.

Here's the problem: In order to be able to mock out file accesses I have to introduce a WinApiInterface (or whatever you want to call it, like FileIoInterface) which must be given to the constructor of the CsvTableFile class. This however shows everyone the implementation, which is commited to OpenFile. If I want to change the internals from OpenFile to ifstream, I have to change the constructor, as then I don't need a WinApiInterface to pass to the class but a FileStreamInterface.

I'm not particularly happy with the situation but I can't come up with a solution. Am I missing something?

```
class WinApiInterface {
public:
    virtual HFILE WINAPI OpenFile(
       _In_  LPCSTR     lpFileName,
       _Out_ LPOFSTRUCT lpReOpenBuff,
       _In_  UINT       uStyle ) = 0;
}

class WinApi : public WinApiInterface {
public:
    virtual HFILE WINAPI OpenFile(
       _In_  LPCSTR     lpFileName,
       _Out_ LPOFSTRUCT lpReOpenBuff,
       _In_  UINT       uStyle ) { 
           return ::OpenFile(lpFileName, lpReOpenBuff, lpReOpenBuff);};
}


class TableFileInterface {
public:
    virtual int Open(std::string file) = 0;
    virtual int Close() = 0;

    virtual std::string GetCellAsString(size_t row; size_t column) = 0;
    virtual double GetCellAsDouble(size_t row; size_t column) = 0;
}

class CsvTableFile : public TableFileInterface {
public:
    CsvTableFile(const WinApiInterface& win_api)
       : win_api_(win_api){};
    ~CsvTableFile(){};

    virtual int Open(std::string file) { *CODE USING win_api_.OpenFile(...)*};
    virtual int Close() {...};

    std::string GetCellAsString(size_t row; size_t column) {...};
    double GetCellAsDouble(size_t row; size_t column) {...};

protected:
    WinApiInterface win_api_;
}
```

Comment: `WinApiInterface` is an abstract class and can not be instantiated as a class member. You can store it either as a plain reference or using a smart pointer.

Comment: Define an interface of a class that provides just the lines to handle. Your CvsTableFile class then takes an object that implements this interface to get the lines to process. Then you can write one class that actually reads from the file, another class for your tests etc.

Comment: @smkanadl: you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Rene: Very smart. I think I'll try that, too! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your main goal here is to keep `CsvTableFile` from needing to change, you could template it and shift the opening logic to the template parameter object.

```
template <class T>
class CsvTableFile : public TableFileInterface {
public:
    CsvTableFile(const T& _fileopener):fileopener(_fileopener){}

    int Open(std::string file) { fileopener.OpenFile(...); }

    T& fileopener;
    ...
};
```

Then create a class for every type of file handling you want to employ and implement an `OpenFile` method in each of those classes.

Comment: Great approach! This solved my problem in an elegant way. Thanks!